# Prove that the complex function: $\frac{z}{ \sin(\pi/z)}$ has an anti-derivative on $\mathbb{C} \setminus D(0,1)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, laurent-series

> Prove that the function $\frac{z}{\sin(\pi/z)}$ of a complex variable has an anti-derivative on $\mathbb{C} \setminus D(0,1)$.

My attempt: I tried to develop the Laurent series at $z=0$ but without any success.

Any suggestions on how to prove that using Laurent series?

Comment: The function is not defined at $z=1$.

Comment: @copper.hat True, I guess it should be $\overline{D(0,1)}$ which makes more sense since as a result  $\mathbb{C}\setminus \overline{D(0,1)}$will be an open set.

Comment: @JulianMejia: I was just being a penant :-)

Comment: Of course, a penant is just a poorly spelt pedant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is an even function. Therefore, its Laurent series is of the form $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^{2n}$, which has an antiderivative: $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{a_n}{2n+1}z^{2n+1}$.

Comment: Interesting, I guess this technique works as long $a_{-1}=0$.

Comment: Indeed it does.